# Searching a book with people who have several mouths

Tags: story-identification

I've been searching for a book series I read roughly 3 years ago. The first book followed a group expedition through a dangerous wasteland with monsters. They are saved by people riding giant lion type  creatures the people wear masks hiding the fact that they have several mouths. They act like they are peaceful but it's a big plan from their volcano gods to take revenge and attack the other kingdoms.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "a few years ago?"  Where did you read these; were they paper books or e-books?

Comment: Thank you. It was roughly 3 years ago I read them in paperback.